# pre-loading data in wicket paged table

Tags: asynchronous, wicket

Do to a slow backend, we have been asked to pre-load and cache data on a pageable table (DataTable).

The idea is to maintain a cache in the ISortableDataProvider and ask the backend for larger chunks than we display per page. This way, the user has not to wait each time he switching to the next table-page.

The troubling part is the idea that fetching the next chunk should run in the background. What would be a good approach?

a) starting a new background thread to to the fetching

b) trigger an Ajax call do the background fetching (and storing in the cache)

I don't really like any of the options as I foresee a number of problems.

Any comments?

Comment: I have used a background thread in the past. I don't know if it is a favorite solution, so I would love to hear what you end up with. In my case, I was using a tree with an ISortableDataProvider, so it is a little different as I didn't need to know the size of the whole data set to build a paging navigator. What I did was load the initial set the user needs immediately into the cache and then use a background thread to load the rest. The ISortableDataProvider would request data from the cache.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is not really a Wicket related problem.
I think you should focus on the service level + some caching solution.

Wicket could be a solution only if you decide to put the extra data (prev/next page(s)) in the Wicket components.

Comment: Hi Martin: that was precisely my idea, to put that data into the wicket component. Right now I try to work without a background thread but load more data than need for a page and cache it in the component/dataprovider. Having more than one thread updating that data introduces more trouble than worth in my opinion.